# Spring Web Flow request mappings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping, spring-webflow-2

I am adding Spring Web Flow 2 to a very large existing web application that does not currently use Spring MVC or Web Flow. My task is to have the Web Flow triggered by going to mySite.com/flows, and I am having difficulties. My approach was to set up the DispatcherServlet with mapping of `/flows/*` and map Web Flow to `/flows`. Here is my web.xml where the DispatcherServlet is configured:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flow</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/flowContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flow</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flows/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried several methods to get the Web Flow to map to `/flows`. My first try was to use a flow-registry with `base-path` setting:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/app/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

My understanding is that this will take the folder structure inside of the `/WEB-INF/app/flows` to create the request mapping. My first test was to add my flow, `booking-flow.xml` inside a subfolder called `booking` (`/WEB-INF/app/flows/booking`). And, great! - it worked as expected. I was able to access the flow from mySite.com/flows/booking. OK, but I don't want `/booking` in the URL, so I moved the `booking-flow.xml` out of the `booking` folder, and straight into `WEB-INF/app/flows` and expected that to work for me, but it did not - I don't think the flow mapped at all.

Does anyone know how I can map a flow to the root of the DispatcherServlet mapping, or is there a better way to approach this? I don't want the DispatcherServlet to handle any requests outside of `/flows` in my application. Is it just me, or is there very little documentation available on Spring Web Flow?

Thanks!

Comment: best option without making any changes in dir structure is to remove `flows` from the `base-path`. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) this way to map your flow to mySite.com/flows

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings" value="flows=flowController" />
</bean>

<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
</webflow:flow-executor>

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/app/flows">    
    <webflow:flow-location path="booking-flow.xml" id="flows"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be like this

```
<!-- Registry of executable flows -->
<flow:flow-registry flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices"
    id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/">
    <flow:flow-location id="hello" path="hello-flow.xml" />
    <flow:flow-location path="start-flow.xml" id="main" />

</flow:flow-registry>
```

invoke flows using the id's like **hello**.htm or **hello**.html depending upon the url mapping.first view state in the respective file will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current file structure setup you can either do

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/app/flows">    
    <webflow:flow-location path="booking-flow.xml" id="flows"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

i.e you give id explicitly in which case URL applicable would be - `mySite.com/flows`

OR

you can remove flows from base context -

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/app">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

and out your file in `/WEB-INF/app/flows/booking-flow.xml`. This will automatically generate id corresponding to path between base path and your file name - which will be `flows` and again URL applicable will be  `mySite.com/flows`